# Initialize record on cell enter of XamDataGrid

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

Assume we have a XamDataGrid with 10 columns.

Column 1 is a XamComboEditor bound to a collection in the model

- This can't be changed, the data is coming from a server and the combo's collection is based on different selections within the model so it's very dynamic.

Columns 2 - 10 are just normal alpha numeric fields

The problem:

When you enter a alpha numeric and start typing the model is initialized and everything is fine. However, if you go to the very last row, the non-initialized empty one, and click on the combo editor before entering any data into any of the other fields, the combo editor is empty.

Now I am well aware of why this is happening, it's clear that this is due to the model not being initialized yet. I'm just not sure the best method to fix this.

I would hope there is a property on the XamDataGrid that adjusts when the record is initialized but I've searched the Infragistics documentation and examples and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are events for:

- `EditModeStarting`
- `EditModeStarted`
- `EditModeEnding`
- `EditModeEnded`

  ```
  private void OnCellEditModeStarting(object sender, EditModeStartingEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Cell.Field.Name == "TotalQuantity")
      {
          DataRecord record = args.Cell.Record;

          if (record == null)
              return;

          MyGridEntry item = record.DataItem as MyGridEntry;
          // Do a thing
      }
  }
  ```

You can also respond to the `InitializeRecord` event. It can fire for multiple reasons, such as cell editing, so check the state of your row model when responding to it. All these events are on the parent grid, not any FieldLayouts or Fields.

```
<i:XamDataGrid    x:Name="myGrid"
                  InitializeRecord  ="OnInitializeRecord"
                  EditModeStarting    ="OnEditModeStarting">
```